# Stuck at grub rescue> after deleting ubuntu 13.10 from windows 8

Tags: grubrescue

I have deleted ubuntu 13.10 from windows 8 disk management and extended a drive using that freed space...
After doing that when I restarted my laptop I got stuck at grub rescue and not able to boot to windows 8 ..neither I can open the BIOS section..
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Deleting Ubuntu from dual boot your grub deleted. Now you have only Windows 8 in your system

1. Step : If you have recovery partation then run recovery to recover windows 8 Other wise you should boot from windows 8 cd and repair MBR from your windows 8 CD. It will repair your MBR and boot from windows 8 OS.

Comment: Can I do that using a flash drive ?

Comment: yes,you can do it.

Comment: But how to Boot using USB when I am not able to enter in my Boot Options ??

Comment: Which (Laptop) model no you have? I think F12 or F10 Functions keys will take you to the Boot Options. Make sure your USB should be bootable.